# Java - use variable from another class

Tags: java

I have 2 classes in java. I want to use the variable from class Graph "nr_noduri" in the class Population. How can i do that? The problem is that i pick "nr_noduri" in the main when i create the objects. For example Graph g = new Graph(5).

```
package tema_top_v3;

public class Graph {

    public int nr_noduri ;
    int [][]a;

    Graph(int v){
    this.nr_noduri = v;
    a = new int [v][v];
    }

    void link(int x, int y){
        a[x][y] = 1;  
    }

}

public class Population {

    int X = 50;

    public void generate_population(int N,int nr_culori){
        N = X;

        String [][]X = new String [N][nr_noduri];
        String colors1[] = {"red", "blue", "green"};   
        String colors2[] = {"red", "blue", "green", "yellow"};  

        if(nr_culori==3){
        for(int i = 0; i<N;i++){
           for(int j = 0; j<nr_noduri; j++){
               X[i][j] =  colors1[new Random().nextInt(colors1.length)];
           }         
        } 
        }

        if(nr_culori==4){
            for(int i = 0; i<N;i++){
               for(int j = 0; j<nr_noduri; j++){
                   X[i][j] =  colors2[new Random().nextInt(colors2.length)];
               }         
            } 
            }

    }
}
```

Comment: They are no relation between those. `Population` don't use `Graph` or inverse. So what instance of `Graph` should this use ?

Comment: could you please add your `main` method?

Comment: A) please read some beginner book/tutorial. What you are asking about is something **every newbie** comes along. B) read about java naming conventions - you dont use the underbar for variable or method names.

Comment: I don't have the main yet . I work to a project " Graph coloring problem using genetic algorithm".

Comment: You should first think. The design is incorrect. A Graph should probably be link to `Population` instance or a list of those. Take your pencil and a sheet of paper and think before implementing.

Comment: Then you are absolutely overburdening yourself. Sorry, but start reading https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ instead. You are unable to crawl, but yet you want to go for hurdle racing. Not an efficient approach. Step back, learn the basics before going for advanced assignments.

Comment: @AxelH In order to be able to *think up* a solution, one needs the "mental building blocks" to do that. And maybe that is just me, but to me it seems, that the OP is lacking those basic building blocks. But you can't build a house from thin air.

Comment: Either `Population` needs a reference to a `Graph` instance, or `nr_noduri` needs to be static.

Comment: @GhostCat nah, using a hammer until it fits ! It always works ;) I was editing to add a similar message than yours, but I liked your `you are unable to crawl...` part so I cancel the edit ^^

Comment: @AxelH So true. I like your attitude. Last week my wife asked me to mount some pictures to the wall. But I only had screws and a hammer; no nails, no screw driver. I suggested that using the hammer I could still solve the problem, but my wife didnt like that idea at all. But why? You know, I have a hammer there!

Comment: @GhostCat women ....  always bothering with small details like wall integrity and stuff. We can always patch the problem later ;) (Have a nice day, mine is over, logging out)

Comment: @AxelH Cant log out yet. I need 15 more rep to hit the daily cap ;-(